Oracle Apex 22.1 IG Save validations
I have an IG:
Select emp_name, dept_name, BU, org_unit from emp_organizations;

I want to add validations such that when a new record is created app should check if dept_name exists in the database. If yes, it should save.
If No,a prompt shall come, "Do you want to save this new value?"
If yes, it should save the new record else save action should be ignored.
What kind of validations/DA logic can i use to achieve this?

Actually there might be 2 different approaches for your needs:

If you can ignore that if the dept isn't found, you ignore it and ask users to create the dept first on its page. In this case, you just need to use a custom save process for your Interactive Grid.
If you really need that if the dept isn't found, user should decide if the dept shall be created. In this case you need a AJAX process to interact with the user (whether dept will be created or not)

For the first approach:
Create a new process of type "Interactive Grid Automatic Row Processing (DML)", Settings-> Target Type -> PL/SQL Code.
And the code you need should be something like:
DECLARE
v_cnt number;
BEGIN 
    IF :APEX$ROW_STATUS = 'D' THEN -- DELETE
        RETURN;
    ELSIF :APEX$ROW_STATUS = 'C' THEN -- CREATE
    SELECT count(1) 
    INTO v_cnt
    from your_table;
    if v_cnt = 0 -- you need to create your dept with the details 
     insert into dept_table(name) values (:DEPT_NAME);
     -- and probably other DML operations here by your needs.
    end if;
        RETURN;
    ELSIF :APEX$ROW_STATUS = 'U' THEN -- UPDATE
        RETURN;
    END IF;
END;

*Don't forget to set Execute Condition to For each row for this approach.
For the second approach, you need a custom Save button on you IG that will execute a dynamic action with a Javascript Code as:
var widget = apex.region('your_ig_id').widget();
var grid = widget.interactiveGrid('getViews','grid');
var model = grid.model;
model.forEach(function(r) {
    apex.server.process("AJAX_DEPT_EXISTS", {
    x01: model.getValue(r,"DEPT_NAME")
  }, {
    success: function(pData) {
      if (pData.exists) {
        apex.page.submit();
      } else {
        apex.message.confirm( "Department doesn't exists. Do you want it to be created?", function( okPressed ) { 
          if( okPressed ) {
              //call another AJAX process here to save the dept and then submit the page
              apex.server.process("AJAX_INSERT_DEPT", {
                x01: model.getValue(r,"DEPT_NAME")
                }, {
                success: function(pData) {
                  apex.page.submit();
                }
                });
          }
      });
      }
    }
  });
})

The idea here is when save button is called, it should check if the dept exists for each row and saves the dept by the confirmation/approval from user.
Then of course you need 2 Ajax process on the page named 'AJAX_DEPT_EXISTS' and 'AJAX_INSERT_DEPT'.
'AJAX_DEPT_EXISTS' should return 'exists' as boolean and the 'AJAX_INSERT_DEPT' should do the inserting like:
begin
    insert into dept_table(dept_name) values (apex_application.g_x01); commmit;
    apex_json.open_object;
    apex_json.write('success', true);
    apex_json.close_object;
end;


Thanks for the solution. ACtually i cant share my actual table name details so chose random columns. it is all part of the same table.. So no separate table for the supposed dept_name column

It'd be even simpler then...

Generally speaking, I don't think that this is the right approach.
Departments should be stored in a separate table (master) and referenced from emp_organizations (detail) by the foreign key constraint. It means that you can't insert a row into emp_organizations unless department exists in its own table.
Note that - although you can create a foreign key on department name, it is far more usual to use some kind of an ID for such a purpose.
List of departments isn't indefinite, so it should be known before inserting anything into emp_organizations. It also means that you can create a list of values (on department name column in the interactive grid) which shows list of all available departments.

As of your question: can you do that? Maybe/probably yes, but I'm not sure it's worth the effort.

[EDIT]
Validation won't help, because - you can check whether that name already exists or not and "alert" user, but validation will stop further execution and you won't be able to save that record.
What you could try to do is to use combination of two dynamic actions. Here's how.
Create page item (let's call it P8_CNT) which will contain number of rows that already contain that DEPT_NAME value; make it hidden.
Create dynamic action on DEPT_NAME column:

set client-side condition (without it, DA would fire as soon as you press the "Add row" button):

item/column is not null
component type: column
column: DEPT_NAME



The first action is Set value:
select count(*)
from emp_organizations
where dept_name = :DEPT_NAME
  and dept_name is not null


affected element is the P8_CNT item

The second one is Confirm:

message: That department does not exist yet. Do you want to save it?
client side condition:

type: item/column = value
component type: item
item: P8_CNT
value: 0



That's all; run the page and try it.

Actually this is sample code. Actual data is different and I cannot post that

Can we just assume it to be the only table and suggest something?

Have a look at edited answer.

I tried this but it doesn't save the record. Should the DA be created on IG save? Sorry if i didn't get this..

DA should be created on DEPT_NAME column (which belongs to the interactive grid). What I described works as I first tried it, and then wrote the answer.

Ok, in my case when i do this, as soon as i fill DEPT_NAME the alert pops up instead of coming up on save button click
